# Why is my variable not persisting between routes in flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, global-variables

I am trying to pass 2 variables `name1` and `name2` across all of my routes. I gather the variables in `/home` and they are successfully passed to `/one` and `/two`. However, the variables return `None` when passed to `/three` and I can't figure out why.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    name1 = request.args.get('name1')
    name2 = request.args.get('name2')
    return render_template(
        'home.html',
        name1=name1,
        name2=name2
        )

@app.route('/one')
def one():
    name1 = request.args.get('name1')
    name2 = request.args.get('name2')
    text1 = f"Hello {name1}."
    text2 = f"Hello {name2}."
    return render_template(
        'one.html',
        name1=name1,
        name2=name2,
        text1=text1,
        text2=text2
        )

@app.route('/two')
def two():
    name1 = request.args.get('name1')
    name2 = request.args.get('name2')
    text3 = f"{name1}, ready to begin."
    text4 = f"{name2}, ready to begin."

    return render_template(
        'two.html',
        name1=name1,
        name2=name2,
        text3=text3,
        text4=text4,
        )

@app.route('/three')
def three():
    name1 = request.args.get('name1')
    name2 = request.args.get('name2')
    text6 = f"{name1} and {name2}, lets go!"
    return render_template(
        'three.html',
        name1=name1,
        name2=name2,
        text6=text6,
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here are the html files:

```
# home.html

<p>Enter your names</p>
<form action="{{ url_for('one', name1=name1, name2=name2) }}" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</form>

# one.html
<p>{{text1}}</p>
<p>{{text2}}</p>
<a href="{{ url_for('two', name1=name1, name2=name2) }}">Next</a>


# two.html

<h1> Aftermath of a Fight Intervention Assistant </h1>
<p>{{text3}}</p>
<p>{{text4}}</p>
<a href="{{ url_for('three', name1=name1, name2=name2) }}">Next</a>

# three.html

<p>{{text6}}</p>
```

Comment: What version of Python, Flask, are you using? I just replicated in Python 3.10 and Flask 2.1.2 and it worked just fine.

Comment: It would be better if you used `flask.session`, **in my opinion**.